# Is there a way to add web parts to an individual Blog post?

Tags: web-part, blog

WSS 3.0, standard included Blog template. End user site admin only, no access to server farm etc.

What I need to be able to do is add a unique instance of a content editor web part to each blog post. I do this on our wiki without issue, but apparently the blog post pages don't work the same - adding a web part adds it to all posts identically since they are all the same post.aspx with an ID affixed.

I would just use the Wiki but I've got to have the ability to use Word's easy formatting and blog integration for this particular project. I'm open to alternatives that still let me do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so: a blog post is a list item (as opposite to a wiki which is a page) and all posts are displayed using on and the same page.

Comment: Waldek is correct here.  Blog posts are list items and you cannot insert web parts into the content of list items.  Web parts can only be inserted into "page content".

Comment: Thanks, this helps clarify things.  I'm going to play with some alternatives like a new column and playing with views instead.